# ls: cannot access .gvfs: Permission denied

Tags: gnome-terminal, gvfs

Whenever I run an application in terminal as root (such as `sudo gedit  /etc/default/varnish`) , subsequently when I open another terminal I get "ls: cannot access .gvfs: Permission denied" error at top line of terminal.

I found a solution on the net

```
  umount /path/to/.gvfs
  rm -rf .gvfs
```

but it only fixes problem temporarily.

It appears that I have two mounted instances of **gvfs** in my system

```
  $ sudo mount |grep gvfs
    gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=33)
    gvfsd-fuse on /home/****/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
```

I don't know if it's related to, a few months ago I had to change permission in my home folder like

```
  sudo chown -R $USER:www-data
```

Would you please help me fix it?

EDIT:
After I unmount `/run/user/1000/gvfs` I don't get that error.

Comment: And that's one of the reasons why you shouldn't run `sudo` with graphical programs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why user should never use normal sudo to start graphical application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application)

Comment: @muru
Thank you for the link, it explains well why I should not run sudo to open graphical applications. But I still wonder why I began to get that error message

Comment: Quoting the top answer in the linked question: "This will sometimes result in the configuration files being owned by root and thus inaccessible to you (when you later run the program as yourself and not as root)."

Comment: I suspect this particular situation may actually *not* be related to [running graphical programs with straight sudo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application). Permissions/access on users `.gvfs` folders [have always been interesting and (to some of us) surprising](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77592/11938).

Comment: Unmounting fixed this issue for me too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running graphical applications with `sudo` can sometimes lead to problems like this.

**Explanation**

`sudo` runs the program with superuser privileges (like running as root), but the program still sees the current home directory as *your* home directory.

So, when the software writes its configuration files, it'll end up creating files in your home directory that are owned by the *root* user.  You end up with files you yourself cannot edit or delete, and software running as you won't be able to modify it either, leading to more problems.

**What is the best solution?**

There is an alternative: `gksudo`.

This variant of sudo will set up environment variables, such as the home directory, in such a way that makes running graphical applications as root a lot safer and won't confuse programs into creating root-owned files in your home directory.

**Why does this affect graphical applications?**

This doesn't just affect graphical applications, nor does it affect all graphical applications.  It affects applications that store configuration inside the current user's home directory.  This is just more common among graphical applications.

Sometimes applications will be able to detect if they're run with sudo and adjust their behaviour accordingly, but this is not common with graphical applications which are usually not expected to be run with sudo.

**How do I fix the problem?**

You'll need to find root-owned files and directories within your home directory and remove them.  It's better to remove them than change their ownership in my opinion, as they were not intended for your user, but the root user, so there may be unexpected effects if you simply change ownership.  You can of course back them up in case you decide there's something you want in them later.

To find root-owned files in your home directory:

```
find ~ -user root
```

If you are still having problems with some applications (run as your user), try rebooting to clear out `/tmp` and anything still running.  Occasionally some applications might have corrupted their existing config files and need you to remove *all* their configuration in your home directory, but hopefully this won't be the case for many.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. How can I fix it? Or everybody has the same issue as me?

Comment: By using `gksudo` instead of `sudo` when running graphical programs.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong in my system.

Comment: Yes, other than the possibility you now have root-owned files in your home directory that shouldn't be root-owned.

Answer (score 3):

Just give the user permissions to the `.gvfs/` and it should fix it.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gvfs/
```

Comment: All these years... the answer was right in front of me. Thanks. Is there any downside at all to opening up the permissions in this way?