# Cannot Mount SMB Share via GVFS

Tags: mount, gvfs

For some reason, one user on a shared system is having access issues with gvfs.  The system is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and fully patched up through November 14, 2021.

The process we use to get the mount (each user has their own share on this server):

`/usr/bin/dbus-run-session bash`
`/usr/bin/gio mount smb://username@server/sharename`

For all of our users except one, this command runs asks for Domain and password and sets up the connection in:

`/run/user/1039/gvfs/`

For this one user who cannot connect, it starts to do the connection and then fails with the following error:

"fusermount: failed to access mountpoint /run/user/1039/gvfs: Permission denied"

I took a look at the permissions for that folder and the permissions are r-x------, owned by the user.  I've compared this to two known working accounts and those permissions are rwx------ owned by their respective users.

I asked the user with the non-working account to try to change the permissions using chmod, but despite not getting an error, the permissions never seem to change.

Does anyone know any way to get these permissions to set properly, or perhaps reset GVFS, assuming that's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with some help from this answer from several years ago:

[ls: cannot access .gvfs: Permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524667/ls-cannot-access-gvfs-permission-denied)

It turns out that GVFS was already listed as mounted for the user/share, but had for some reason either not actually mounted or didn't fully unmount.

Either way, unmounting and redoing the mount setup worked.